# Hostname of incoming apple push notification ? + iphone

Tags: iphone

any idea of the hostname that is sending the incoming push notification? The reason for this is because i have an iPad that uses a wifi connection to a network that have limited access so i would have to know the hostname to specifically allow the hostname to be able to connect and send the push notification. Im thinking that maybe it has something to do with aosnotify.mac.com

Answer (score 0):

Do you know for a fact it's a problem? Because I haven't heard anywhere about having to set up special routing on the network for APNs to show up. I use NAT on my home network, and however Apple works to connect the device to their APN servers, it does just fine.

Comment: err im actually currently using a network which has very tight network security. so we have to filter off stuff.